# How to have multiple audio streams play overlapping in iOS?

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I am defining three area of my screen as 'hot-spots' so if there is any touch detected, it plays a zone-specific sound. It all works great, except that if I click on zone 1 and then zone 2, the zone 2 sounds cuts off zone 1. I want the sound of any zone to play until completed. So, if I click zone 1 and then zone 2, zone 1's sound will keep playing, and zone 2 will play over zone 1.

Here is the code I currently have (which works fine, but doesn't allow audio overlaps):

```
   if(point.y < 316 && point.y > 76 && point.x < 220 && point.x > 200)
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/sound1.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

        NSError *error;
        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
        audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;

        if (audioPlayer == nil)
            NSLog([error description]);
        else
            [audioPlayer play];
    }
    if(point.y < 316 && point.y > 76 && point.x < 260 && point.x > 240)
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/sound2.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

        NSError *error;
        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
        audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;

        if (audioPlayer == nil)
            NSLog([error description]);
        else
            [audioPlayer play];
    }
    if(point.y < 316 && point.y > 76 && point.x < 300 && point.x > 280)
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/sound3.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

        NSError *error;
        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
        audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;

        if (audioPlayer == nil)
            NSLog([error description]);
        else
            [audioPlayer play];
    }
```

Can someone please help me figure out how to make these sounds overlap? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're just reassigning audioPlayer for each case.  If audioPlayer is already playing one sound and then you reassign it to play the other sound, the original audioPlayer will be destroyed and stop playing.

The way I've solved this problem in the past is to set up multiple AVPlayer objects, like:

```
AVPlayer *_player[MAX_CHANNELS];
NSUInteger _currentChannel;
```

then to play:

```
_player[_currentChannel] = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
_currentChannel++;
if (_currentChannel == MAX_CHANNELS) {
    _currentChannel = 0;
}
```

Then you don't get an infinite number of overlapping sound effects, but you can predefine some "reasonable" number as MAX_CHANNELS and have that many overlapping effects before the next sound stops the first sound.